# Swipe in Polymer

Tags: polymer

Does Polymer 1.0 have any SwipeEventListeners? So that, if the window is swiped on a mobile screen, an event is triggered?

Like :

```
Polymer({

    is: 'my-element',

    behaviors: [
        Polymer.IronSwipeBehavior
    ],

    listeners: {
        'iron-swipe': '_onIronSwipe'
    },

    _onIronSwipe: function(){
         if( swipe == left )
         /* Do something */
         else if ( swipe == right )
         /* Do something else */
    }

});
```

If Polymer doesn't have it, please suggest a lightweight library which will do the job.

Comment: Polymer has track events used for dragging and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

As Neil mentioned, polymer has [gesture events](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#gestures) for up, down, tap, and track, in this case, you could use the track event for the swipe.

Answer (score 1):

From https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-swipeable-container:

> **iron-swipeable-container** is a container that allows any of its nested children (native or custom elements) to be swiped away. By default it supports a curved or horizontal transition, but the transition duration and properties can be customized.

Throws `iron-swipe` event

Answer (score 1):

I think, that these events are, what you are searching for:

`down`, `up`, `track` and `tap`:

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/gesture-events

Answer (score 0):

For a mobile scenario I've used a community element called `iron-swipeable-pages` which was really helpful.

Check it out on customelements.io [here](https://customelements.io/MeTaNoV/iron-swipeable-pages/)